# Having problem with TimerTask and Timer

Tags: java, timer, timertask

```
    brightonStores = BrightonUtil.getStoreInfo(file.getName(), dir.getAbsolutePath(),mailInfoST);

    String status = "604";
    if (!brightonStores.isEmpty()) {
        status = brightonStoreService.saveDeleteBrightonStore(brightonStores,mailInfoST);
        storeLog.info("Adding Store records Status:: "+status);
        if (status.equals("600")) {
            storeLog.info("File: " + file.getName() + " No of records: " + brightonStores.size() + " :: Added");
            mailInfoST.setToSend(false);
            //mailTimerTaskST.cancel();
        } else {                                    
            storeLog.info("File: " + file.getName() + " :: Error in adding records");    
            writer.append("File: " + file.getName() + " :: Error in adding records"+"\n" + mailInfoST.getResult());
            writer.close();
            BrightonUtil.setMailInfo(mailInfoST, true, false, "File: " + file.getName() + " :: Error in adding records");
            mailTimerST.schedule(mailTimerTaskST, new java.util.Date(), 1000*configurationManager.getFileUploadErrorMailTimer());
        }
    } else {
        storeLog.info("File: " + file.getName() + " :: Error in adding records");
        storeLog.info("File: " + file.getName() + " :: No record found ");    

        writer.append("File: " + file.getName() + " :: Error in adding records");
        writer.append("\nFile: " + file.getName() + " :: No record found ");

        if(null != mailInfoST.getResult()){
            storeLog.info(mailInfoST.getResult());
            writer.append("\n"+mailInfoST.getResult());
        }

        writer.close();
        BrightonUtil.setMailInfo(mailInfoST, true, false, "File: " + file.getName() + " :: Error in adding records");
        mailTimerST.schedule(mailTimerTaskST, new java.util.Date(), 1000*configurationManager.getFileUploadErrorMailTimer());
    }
} else if(validationStatus.equals("604")){
    storeLog.error("Error in Brighton Store data file :: Invalid structure or value :: "+ file.getName());
    writer.append("Error in Brighton Store data file :: Invalid structure or value :: "+ file.getName() + "\n" + mailInfoST.getResult());
    writer.close();

    BrightonUtil.setMailInfo(mailInfoST, true, false, "Error in Brighton Store data file :: Invalid structure or value :: "+ file.getName());
    mailTimerST.schedule(mailTimerTaskST, new java.util.Date(), 1000*configurationManager.getFileUploadErrorMailTimer());
} else {
    storeLog.error("Error in reading data from Brighton Store file :: " + file.getName());
    writer.append("Error in reading data from  Brighton Store file :: " + file.getName()+ "\n" + mailInfoST.getResult());
    writer.close();

    BrightonUtil.setMailInfo(mailInfoST, true, false, "Error in reading data from Brighton Store file :: " + file.getName());
    mailTimerST.schedule(mailTimerTaskST, new java.util.Date(), 1000*configurationManager.getFileUploadErrorMailTimer());
}

brightonStores = null;
java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

Is it possible reshedule TimerTask in a Timer..

Comment: mailTimerTaskST - timer task object I am trying to restart the task but I am getting an exception Error occured during Inventory File import job :: Task already scheduled or cancelled

Answer (score 0):

You can't reschedule a TimerTask within a Timer.  If you want to change the schedule that the task is run on, you need to cancel the old timer and create a new one.